# Looping through DataTables to find differences

Tags: c#

I've looked at this so long, I can't see what I'm doing. I'm trying to loop through two datatables in C# and build a list of items in `table2` which do not have an exact match or are not included in `table1`. However, I keep getting the full list of `table2` items.  It's a stupid logic error that I can't see. Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Much thanks.

```
string results = null;
foreach (DataRow row1 in table2.Rows)
{
    int x = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row2 in table1.Rows)
    {
        var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
        var array2 = row2.ItemArray;
        if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
        {
            x = 1;
            break; // get out of the loop and continue
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (x == 0)
    {
        results = results + (row1["Drug"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing this in a query? If table 2 doesn't have the same number of rows and in the same order as table 1 you'll never be able to iterate through them this way. Also, unless your code has implemented `IEqualityComparer<T>` SequenceEqual compares that the references are the same, not just the data. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: If you tried to place a breakpoint then you would have noticed that the `x==0` is always true because `array1.SequenceEqual(array2)` is never true. Also shouldn't there be an exception because results is null and then you're adding `(row1["Drug"])`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic works fine.  Here's a dotnet fiddle example using your logic: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4KMQ0w.

Your issue must be to do with the actual values in the two tables.  For example are you clear that all the datatypes are the same in the two tables, there are no long vs int or different string lengths.  If ther are you will need to break the "SequenceEqual" into loop and perform compares against each field manually.

Minor comments on the code:
1. The `var array2 = row2.ItemArray;` should sit above the foreach.
2. The `continue`, whilst not doing any harm, is redundant.
3. instead of `int x = 0;` use `bool found = false;` or something.

If you want a more efficient overall algorithm for the compare, consider loading table1 into a Dictionary and performing a lookup there.  Let me know if you need an example of this.

Good luck.